# Error changing avatar: Make sure to pass a valid image file for the right InputFile parameter (caused by UploadProfilePhotoRequest)

Tags: python, telethon

when i run the script to periodically change the avatar in telegram, i get an error, saying the image file is invalid. but the images are in a supported format (PNG) and are in the same folder as the script

```
import asyncio
import os
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, functions
from PIL import Image

api_id = ''
api_hash = ''
phone_number = ''
avatars = ['C:/AvatarMasterTg/avatar1.png', 'C:/AvatarMasterTg/avatar2.png', 'C:/AvatarMasterTg/avatar3.png']  # Список файлов с аватарками

client = TelegramClient('session_name', api_id, api_hash,
                        device_model="iPhone",
                        system_version="14.8.1",
                        app_version="8.4",
                        lang_code="en",
                        system_lang_code="en-US")

async def change_avatar(event):
    await client.start()
    await client.sign_in(phone_number)

    # В цикле изменяем размер каждой аватарки
    for avatar in avatars:
        try:
            # Изменяем размеры изображения, если необходимо
            image = Image.open(avatar)
            if image.width < 200 or image.height < 200:
                image = image.resize((200, 200))

            if image.width > 10000 or image.height > 10000:
                image = image.resize((10000, 10000))

            # Сохраняем измененное изображение
            image.save(avatar)

            # Загрузка новой аватарки
            print(f"Changing avatar to: {avatar}")
            photo = await client.upload_file(avatar)
            await client(functions.photos.UploadProfilePhotoRequest(photo))
            print("Avatar changed successfully!")

            # Задержка в 30 секунд перед сменой следующей аватарки
            await asyncio.sleep(30)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error changing avatar: {e}")

async def main():
    # Обработчик событий для изменения аватарки
    client.add_event_handler(change_avatar, events.NewMessage)

    await client.start()

    # Вход в аккаунт
    confirmation_code = input('Введите код подтверждения: ')
    await client.sign_in(phone_number, confirmation_code)

    await client.get_dialogs()
    await client.run_until_disconnected()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

tried different ways of specifying the image path, the dimensions

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass `photo` as keyword to `file`, for more info [see that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75827583/13391404)

```py
await client(functions.photos.UploadProfilePhotoRequest(file=photo))
```